# why asp.net identity is deisgned to run authorization when users not even being authenticated in the first place?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-identity

below is the code

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, CustomRequirementHandler>();  // <------------------

        services.AddAuthentication(opts => {
            opts.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;   
        }).AddCookie(opts => {   
            opts.LoginPath = "/signin/401";
            opts.AccessDeniedPath = "/signin/403";
        });

        services.AddAuthorization(opts => {
            opts.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicy(new[] { new CustomRequirement() { Name = "Bob" } }, Enumerable.Empty<string>());          
        });

        services.AddRazorPages();     
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        // ...

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {       
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
```

and when we run the app `AuthorizationMiddleware` still runs if I put a debugger on `CustomRequirementHandler`, execution flow goes there.

But it doesn't make sense to run user-defined `IAuthorizationHandler` when the users is not being authenticated in the first place.

I find the cause is in https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy/AuthorizationMiddleware.cs,193

policyEvaluator.AuthorizeAsync() always run regardless of whether users are being authenticated or not, should asp.net check `HttpContext.User` to see if the user is authenticated or not, if not then skip `policyEvaluator.AuthorizeAsync() call?

Comment: May be to authorize anonymous users?